# Nginx & PHP-FPM 502 bad gateway error

Tags: php, mongodb, nginx

let me explain the situation first, i have a server with 64 GB RAM & 20 Core with 40GB (SSD) . i have about 2000 concurrent user

1 week ago , i was using apache with php 7 but the cpu was 80% sometimes up to 101% , that's because the huge sql inserts, after shifting from apache to Nginx , MySql to MongoDB. the cpu was about 8%.

my problem now is Nginx a lot of times return 502 bad gateway response, i looked for some answers but nothing help me at all, but when i change fpm socket to port `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock` to `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` ngnix always return 502 , and i can't figure it out to know what's the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server is enough powerful to handle **>500 000** requests to application per day (if it's written wisely).

Problem is because of PHP-FPM cannot have more children process to serve more requests.

In apache it was automatically starting with additional apache process.

But Nginx + PHP-FPM gives You freedom how to handle this situations.

Just change Your fpm pool conf: `/etc/php/php-fpm.d/www.conf`  (or whatever You use)

make sure it has this content:

```
pm = static
pm.max_children = 4096
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s
pm.max_requests = 32
```

and then restart php fpm

also edit `nginx.conf` and make sure it has this fields at top:

```
user http;
worker_processes  auto; 

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll; 
}
```

p.s. don't change listen attribute to `ip:port` - socket is faster, cuz in `ip:port` it creates network connection by ip and port, but in socket version it just opens .sock "file".

p.s. don't change `fastcgi_buffers` and etc directives, it will not fix **bad gateway** problem, because of less php-fpm processes.

In my server it's default:

```
fastcgi_buffers 32 1024k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 1024k;
```

p.s. disable unnecessary logging (nginx.conf) to not to make Your disk drive have more IO load:

```
access_log off;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;
```

if You need monitoring use `newrelic` and monitor Your server's network, cpu, mem activity

Comment: how it was helpful! happy to help (:

Comment: actually it helps me to allow more concurrent requests .. and i moved specific part of the project from laravel to phalcon .. and now it works great

Comment: Nice job! Phalcon is beast of PHP frameworks. It saves me CPU and MEM on little DigitalOcean droplets so server can handle more request.

Comment: Actually I must say it my answer is not dedicated to optimize the app speed. It only helps to handle more requests when other child process is busy executing some task. Even in case of phalcon it's also helpful. Because with growing performance You get more users so requests are growing too.

Answer (score -1):

This changes will work: Nginx configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf : Add below under http section in nginx.conf file

> http
>
> {
>
> fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
>
> fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
>
> }